# How to emit multiple items from a custom Retrofit Converter to RxJavaCallAdapterFactory

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, rx-java

My application needs to download and parse a large JSON file.
To avoid any memory related issue I'm parsing the inputstream from response object in a custom Converter in batches of 1000 json objects.

Everything is working well until I want to return the parsed objects to the caller's observable.

My API method is called like this:

```
Observable<MyResponseStream> typesObs = api.getTypes(request.method, request.options);
```

The response is handled by a custom converter

```
public class MyResponseConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

    public MyResponseConverterFactory() {
    }


    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (MyResponseStream.class.equals(type)) {
            // We will process only response where the client wait for I2ctResponseStream
            return MyResponseConverter.INSTANCE;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static MyResponseConverterFactory create() {
        return new MyResponseConverterFactory();
    }

    final static class MyResponseConverter implements Converter<ResponseBody, MyResponseStream> {
        static final MyResponseConverter INSTANCE = new MyResponseConverter();

        @Override
        public MyResponseStream convert(ResponseBody responseBody) throws IOException {
            return new MyResponseStream(responseBody.byteStream());
        }
    }
}
```

The `MyResponseStream` looks like

```
public class MyResponseStream extends MyResponse<ArrayList<JSONObject>> {

    private final static int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;

    public interface ObjectsStreamListener {
        void onObjectsParsed(String parentKey, ArrayList<ObjectNode> items);
    }

    private ArrayList<ObjectNode> mItems;
    private ObjectMapper mMapper;
    private ObjectsStreamListener mListener;
    private InputStream mInputStream;                

    public MyResponseStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super();
        mInputStream = inputStream;
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

   public void start(ObjectsStreamListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        if (mInputStream != null) {
            parse();
        }
    }

    private void parse() {
        try {
            mMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonParser parser = mMapper.getFactory().createParser(mInputStream);
            String key;
            JsonToken currentToken = parser.nextToken();

            while (currentToken != null) {
                parser.nextFieldName();
                key = parser.getCurrentName();

                if ("method".equals(key)) {
                    method = parser.nextTextValue();
                } else if ("success".equals(key)) {
                    isSuccess = parser.nextIntValue(0) == 1;
                    Cs.e("isSuccess " + isSuccess);
                } else if ("data".equals(key)) {
                    currentToken = parser.nextToken();
                    parseData(parser);
                } else {
                    currentToken = parser.nextToken();
                }
            }
            parser.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void parseData(JsonParser parser) throws IOException {
        String currentKey;

        ObjectNode node;
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            // Consume FIELD_NAME token
            parser.nextFieldName();

            // Get parent key (ex groups)
            currentKey = parser.getCurrentName();

            while (parser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
                while (parser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                    node = mMapper.readTree(parser);
                    mItems.add(node);
                    if (mItems.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {
                        if (mListener != null) {
                            mListener.onObjectsParsed(currentKey, mItems);
                            mItems.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!mItems.isEmpty()) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onObjectsParsed(currentKey, mItems);
                    mItems.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For getting the parsed objects I'm registering a listener

```
typesObs.map(responseStream -> {
            responseStream.start(new MyResponseStream.ObjectsStreamListener() {
                @Override public void onObjectsParsed(String parentKey, ArrayList<ObjectNode> items) {
                    Cs.e("parentKey " + parentKey + " items " + items);
                }
            });
            return responseStream;
        })
```

This approach is working but it doesn't look like a good solution since I'm not taking advantage of RxJava observable in any way.

My question: Is there a way to call the result observable `onNext()` from a converter?
I want to replace

```
mListener.onObjectsParsed(currentKey, mItems);
```

with something like

```
retrofit.getRxCallAdapterFactory().getCallerObservable().onNext(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take is to create an adapter instead of a converter.

This approach would function somewhat in the following order:

1. Check if the type is `Observable<MyResponseStream>`
2. Use `retrofit.callAdapter(...)` to retrieve the adapter for `Observable<Response>`
3. Create a custom adapter that delegates the creation of the observable to the previously retrieved adapter, then apply operations to create the `Observable<MyResponseStream>` to the returned observable.